# How can i capture this type of #define in webgl

Tags: three.js, glsl

I'm working with a shader that has a statement:

```
#define SHADER_NAME MeshDepthMaterial
```

I'd like to prevent something from being redeclared:

```
#if SHADER_NAME != MeshDepthMaterial 
  varying vec2 foo;
#endif
```

But i'm not sure how and if this can be done. Can it be done and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `SHADER_NAME` constant is never used by Three.js for conditionals. (I don't think there's a way to compare to `MeshDepthMaterial` because it's not really a numeric value. Is it a string? Who knows!)

Instead, what Three.js does is [testing if something is defined or not defined](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/envmap_physical_pars_fragment.glsl.js#L78). For example:

- If it's a `MeshStandardMaterial`, it adds `#define STANDARD`
- If it's a `MeshPhysicalMaterial` it adds `#define PHYSICAL`

then it uses this define to test what material you're dealing with

```
#ifdef PHYSICAL
    // Perform physical material declarations
#elif defined( STANDARD )
    // Perform standard material declarations
#else
    // Neither type is defined
#endif
```

(you have to use `#elif defined()` because `#elseifdef` does not exist. You can see all available preprocessor directives [on this chart, page 3](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf), under "Preprocessor")

In order to add this type of functionality to your custom materials, you'll have to do it in JavaScript:

```
if (material.type = "CustomDepthMaterial") {
    material.defines = { "DEPTH": "" };
}
```

... in your shader, this should yield...

```
#define SHADER_NAME CustomDepthMaterial
#define DEPTH
```

... and then you can check if `DEPTH` is defined or not.

Comment: I still don't understand what this declaration does. `DEPTH` i can see being interpreted as "true/false". Is it just something that gets stripped, what if i were to add a list of "arguments"?

Comment: @pailhead I haven't been able to find a strictly *functional* purpose for `SHADER_NAME`, it might be there for convenience. However, I've seen some GLSL debuggers that display this name, which makes it easier to find the shaders you're looking for.

Comment: It sounds like it ends up being very similar to a comment?